# setup JAVA_HOME in jenkins centos

Tags: java, jenkins, continuous-integration, java-6

I am trying to set  **JAVA_HOME** in my Jenkins to run a maven project. So I went

> Jenkins-> Global tool configuration-> JDK

and added my JDK path as /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java.

This is the path where the JDK is installed, I have confirmed this by mentioned [Ref](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/jdk-path-in-centos7-4175577616/) here

Actual error I am getting below the input box is

> /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java is not a directory on
>   the Jenkins master (but perhaps it exists on some agents)

Comment: Can you try just using till: /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64

Comment: As that points to the JAVA_HOME and the jenkins should figure out the rest

Comment: @Curious getting the same results.

Comment: ok, is the JDK available in the Jenkins master?

Comment: What is Jenkins master? How we can check it?

Comment: You mean the master node?

Comment: I tried to add JAVA_HOME in master node but it throwing "403 No valid crumb was included in the request" :(

Comment: anyone there to help me on this?

Comment: I believe you have only installed the runtime and not the development kit. Can you try installing jdk as well using : yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel